# Can multiple Jenkins masters share a slave box (& know about utilisation)

Tags: jenkins

In my company we are currently running Jenkins in a traditional master/slave setup for CI. We have 1 master and 4 slaves, so a fairly small setup.

2 of the slave boxes are high-powered VMs to run HP Fortify security scanning, which is fairly resource-hungry: it maxes out the VMs resources.

Due to increasing numbers of development teams wishing to utilise this model, we're looking to move to a distributed CI model, where each team runs their own CI infrastructure, but keep the high-powered VMs as they are (they are harder to acquire with our current company setup).

My question therefore is:

Is there a way to have multiple Jenkins masters connect to the same slave VM in such a way as they know about currently running jobs of other (unknown) Jenkins masters, and can queue as a result?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your team grows as your infrastructure i think you could afford to use Jenkins Operation Center from CloudBees.

[It support share slaves](https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cjoc-user-guide/shared-slaves.html)

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn't aware of this. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

With right configuration several **masters** can be running on the same machine.

As for *inter-master* configuration it's little more complicated. 
Part of it could be obtained by OSS plug-ins like:

- [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin)
- [Build Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin)
- REST API / CLI

But most of all you should answer yourself **why** not utilize single **master** instead.

Comment: It's a fair point. More projects and teams in our company are looking to work in this way. Our thinking behind this was 2-fold:

1) Each team would have access to their own self-service CI stack that could be spun up & torn down as needed

2) We've had trouble with many modifications being made to the master box, leading to technical debt and problems. 

Do you think it would be a preferable approach to more closely control administration of the master, and simply allow the creation/tear-down of per-project jobs?

Comment: @jamie--stewart I would prefer to have tighter control over Jenkins configuration, rather than risking maintaining several different instances. I you are planning some automation on top of Jenkins, one instance is also easier to handle.